# Inaccurate result while clipping on gis data using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, geometry, clip

I am trying clip polyline data using a polygon geometry. I am using itopologicaloperator to do this task. However, resultant clipped data is off by 1 feet. Meaning that the polylines at the boundaries of the polygon geometry goes beyond the boundary by 1 feet.

Here is my case:

1. the polygon geometry is in GCS_North_American_1983
2. the polylines are in GCS_WGS_1984

I tried to generate the result by projecting the polygon geometry data to GCS_WGS_1984 ((I used NAD1983_To_WGS1984_5 for geographic transformation to equidistant conic projection) before clipping the data . The resultant clipped data is not accurate in that polylines cross the polygon by 1 feet or more.

I tried to generate result using ESRI tools with accurate results. I do not understand why I could not do this with my code.

Here is my code:

```
ITopologicalOperator topo;
IFeatureCursor cursubdiv = null;
IClone geoclone = null;
IFeatureCursor curtrack = null;
IFeature feattrack = null;
IGeometry geotrack = null;
IGeoDataset geosubdiv = null;
ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IUnitConverter unitConverter = null;

//tracks are in gcs_1984
//Polygon geometry is in GCS_North_American_1983
//so convert track geometry to gcs_1984
//project clipped data to USA_Contiguous_Equidistant_Conic
try
{

  geosubdiv = (IGeoDataset) psubdivftly.FeatureClass;

  //get the geometry projected
  geoclone = (IClone) clipgeo ;
  IGeometry clipgrid = (IGeometry) geoclone.Clone();
  // this polygon geometry is in GCS_North_American_1983


  ISpatialFilter spfilt = new SpatialFilter();
  //project the polygon geometry to GCS_1984
  clipgrid = ProjectFromEquidistantToGCS(clipgrid);


  spfilt.geometry = clipgrid
  spfilt.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects
  curtrack =  pGeoTrack.FeatureClass.Search(spfilt, true);

  //create featurebuffer to insert clipped data into the input layer
  IFeatureBuffer subdivfeatbuff =  memcliptrackly.FeatureClass.CreateFeatureBuffer();
  IFeatureCursor insertcur = memcliptrackly.FeatureClass.Insert(true);

  //check each feature is within or crosses and add to the virtual track layer.
  while ((feattrack = curtrack.NextFeature ()) != null)
  {
    geotrack = feattrack.ShapeCopy;
    IRelationalOperator relop = (IRelationalOperator)geotrack;
    if (relop.Within(clipgrid) == true)
    {
      geotrack = projectFromGCSToEquidistant2(geotrack); //projects it  to USA_Contiguous_Equidistant_Conic
      subdivfeatbuff.Shape = geotrack;
      insertcur.InsertFeature(subdivfeatbuff);
    }
    else
    {
      if (relop.Crosses(clipgrid) == true)
      {


        topo = (ITopologicalOperator)geotrack;
        //get the clipped geometry
        topo.Clip(clipgrid.Envelope);
        // geoclone = (IClone)topo;
        geotrack = projectFromGCSToEquidistant2((IGeometry)topo); //projects it  to USA_Contiguous_Equidistant_Conic
        subdivfeatbuff.Shape = geotrack;
        insertcur.InsertFeature(subdivfeatbuff);
        }
    }


  }


  insertcur.Flush();
```

Comment: One foot is pretty good, considering the datasets were never designed to work together.  How large are the objects being processed?  What was the accuracy of the collection device?  At what scale was the polygon collected?

Comment: Well with the ArcGIS tools I get very accurate result. I did not understand your other parts. The polygon represents approx. a size of a state. and polyline feature class data has 50,000 records that represent roads.

Comment: I am wondering if I need set xy tolerance ? if so which data's tolerance I need to use? polygons layer's or polylines layer's or the resultant layers tolerance?

Comment: You can't get a result more accurate than the data (even if you set the precision at 1 millimeter).  Given the combination of data sources in different projections, you probably want to set a tolerance much larger than either input layer's tolerance, probably on the order of 1 or 2 meters.

Comment: that is what I thought until I saw the result produced by ArcGIS tool. I must be doing something wrong.